# Issue with subsetting the data in R

Tags: r

My `dput(CIS_data_5)` is, as follows:

```
structure(list(CIS.RECUERDO = structure(c(3L, 3L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 27L, NA, 29L, 29L, 27L, 3L, NA, 14L, 3L, 28L, 
3L, 16L, 2L, 28L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 16L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 25L, 2L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 4L, NA, 
2L, NA, 28L, 2L, 28L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 29L, NA, 16L, 25L, 24L, 28L, 
24L, 29L, 2L, 24L, 4L, 2L, 22L, 27L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 3L, 
16L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 
2L, 29L, 28L, 2L, 29L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 28L, NA, 
29L, 27L, 22L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 
NA, 29L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 
27L, 29L, 2L, 29L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 24L, 14L, 3L, 
28L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 
2L, 29L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 22L, 29L, 14L, NA, 28L, 2L, 24L, 3L, 
29L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 28L, 25L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 
14L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 25L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 
14L, 16L, 24L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 27L, 3L, NA, 
27L, 26L, 26L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 16L, 24L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 25L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 29L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 29L, 2L, 
16L, 3L, 29L, 26L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 24L, 23L, 
2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 29L, NA, 22L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 25L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 25L, 
28L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 24L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 
3L, 16L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 24L, 2L, 4L, 27L, 24L, 
16L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 14L, 16L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 
16L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 27L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 29L, 
27L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 23L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 
27L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 4L, 2L, 27L, 29L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
24L, 27L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 2L, 29L, 28L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 
14L, 2L, 27L, 14L, NA, 4L, 29L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 27L, 4L, 26L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 28L, 
2L, 3L, 25L, 28L, 24L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
26L, 14L, 29L, 23L, 3L, 24L, 29L, 28L, NA, 29L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 23L, 27L, 3L, NA, 29L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 3L, 
28L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 16L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 16L, 
3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 
29L, 4L, 28L, 14L, 25L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 26L, 24L, 3L, 
27L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
16L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 22L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 27L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
27L, 29L, 2L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 29L, 16L, 26L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 
14L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 16L, NA, 23L, 
27L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 
29L, 4L, 28L, 2L, 2L, NA, 27L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 27L, 
4L, 29L, 26L, 29L, 16L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 16L, 27L, 
2L, 9L, NA, 3L, 3L, 14L, 29L, 28L, 2L, 24L, 3L, 29L, 25L, 3L, 
3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 2L, NA, NA, 27L, 4L, 4L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 25L, 16L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 
29L, 27L, 2L, 16L, 16L, NA, 3L, 16L, 28L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 25L, 
29L, 27L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 29L, 28L, 
25L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 3L, NA, 25L, 16L, 27L, 25L, 28L, 
29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 2L, 
3L, 29L, 25L, NA, 14L, 3L, 27L, 4L, 26L, 2L, NA, 4L, 27L, 2L, 
26L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 24L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 24L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 26L, 4L, 3L, 27L, 
14L, 3L, 29L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 28L, 16L, 3L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
29L, 27L, 22L, 28L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA, 29L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 22L, 14L, 3L, 
14L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 3L, 25L, 29L, 14L, 16L, 2L, 
3L, 16L, NA, 3L, 28L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 
28L, 2L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 25L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 26L, 
29L, 28L, 29L, 2L, 16L, 22L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 25L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 29L, 24L, 29L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 29L, NA, 14L, 3L, 
3L, NA, 29L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 22L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 
3L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 4L, 29L, 4L, 16L, 3L, 23L, 
28L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
3L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 28L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 14L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 28L, 29L, 
16L, 4L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 
29L, 14L, 29L, 26L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 
16L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 27L, 16L, 27L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 4L, 
16L, NA, 3L, NA, 27L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 
5L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 5L, 29L, 28L, NA, 27L, 7L, 7L, 
3L, 7L, 29L, 8L, 3L, 27L, 28L, NA, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 5L, 
3L, 28L, 7L, 4L, 25L, 28L, 3L, 3L, NA, 24L, 29L, 4L, 28L, 2L, 
3L, 28L, 27L, 25L, NA, 28L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 28L, NA, 
3L, 3L, NA, 27L, 5L, 7L, NA, 29L, 27L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 25L, 24L, 
8L, 3L, 26L, 28L, 3L, 5L, 29L, NA, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 7L, 
27L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 3L, NA, 29L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 28L, 
3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 29L, NA, 3L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 3L, NA, 
4L, 3L, 27L, 28L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, NA, 7L, 27L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
29L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 8L, 27L, 29L, 28L, 7L, NA, NA, 29L, 
7L, 27L, 3L, 5L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 22L, 29L, 8L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 
3L, 28L, 27L, 3L, 5L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 27L, 8L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 
28L, 4L, NA, 28L, 29L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 27L, 3L, 8L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 
28L, 7L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 24L, 24L, 5L, 27L, 29L, 4L, 29L, 
23L, 27L, 2L, 7L, 27L, 28L, 7L, 28L, 3L, 7L, 22L, 5L, 7L, 29L, 
29L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 22L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 24L, 28L, 5L, NA, 
28L, 23L, 5L, 7L, 27L, 27L, 7L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 27L, 7L, 
5L, 14L, NA, 25L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 29L, 4L, 4L, 7L, NA, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 26L, 24L, 3L, 5L, 29L, 29L, 4L, 29L, 
29L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 7L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 27L, 7L, 3L, 
29L, 3L, 26L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 29L, NA, NA, 28L, 29L, 7L, 5L, 
29L, 27L, 7L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 29L, 7L, 3L, 24L, 27L, 3L, 
8L, 3L, 5L, NA, 3L, 28L, 8L, 27L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 7L, 28L, 24L, 
27L, 23L, 7L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 29L, 25L, 28L, 7L, 
28L, NA, 28L, 7L, 7L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 8L, NA, 27L, 27L, 8L, 7L, 
25L, 3L, 7L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 24L, 7L, 
7L, 28L, 26L, 22L, 7L, NA, 3L, 29L, 5L, 28L, 24L, 2L, 24L, 7L, 
14L, 8L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 25L, 7L, 3L, 26L, 27L, 5L, 27L, 27L, 
24L, 2L, 29L, 5L, 3L, 28L, 8L, 29L, 5L, 28L, NA, 7L, 8L, 16L, 
27L, 29L, 16L, 27L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 16L, 25L, 29L, 16L, 
3L, 16L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 14L, 3L, NA, 29L, 3L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 4L, NA, 3L, 29L, 16L, 28L, 25L, 4L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 
16L, 29L, 16L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 25L, 3L, 14L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 16L, 
NA, 29L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 16L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 
27L, 3L, 29L, 24L, 14L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 23L, 
3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 24L, 3L, 27L, 25L, 29L, 28L, 3L, 27L, NA, 3L, 
28L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 26L, 3L, 3L, NA, 27L, 25L, 24L, 3L, 
3L, 27L, 25L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 22L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 
27L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 25L, 29L, 25L, 2L, 25L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 
16L, 3L, 24L, 28L, 27L, 2L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 
3L, 22L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 2L, NA, 4L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 
3L, 14L, 27L, 2L, 2L, NA, 29L, 14L, 16L, 27L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, NA, 27L, 16L, 27L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 26L, 2L, 
26L, 27L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 4L, 
3L, 24L, 25L, 16L, NA, 3L, 16L, 29L, 16L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 24L, 
14L, 25L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 29L, NA, 4L, 2L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 
27L, 3L, 26L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 14L, NA, 29L, 2L, 14L, 29L, 2L, 
14L, 24L, 24L, 2L, 3L, NA, 29L, 4L, 29L, 14L, 29L, 27L, 16L, 
4L, 29L, 10L, 27L, 29L, 24L, 3L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 29L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 
29L, 2L, 26L, 3L, NA, 27L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 24L, 14L, 29L, 
29L, 2L, 4L, 27L, 4L, 29L, 26L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 
28L, 2L, 22L, NA, 27L, 29L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 4L, 
27L, 4L, 24L, 28L, 4L, 24L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 25L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 26L, 27L, 25L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 22L, 14L, 28L, 3L, 25L, 25L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 26L, 
22L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 25L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 
25L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 
3L, 4L, 26L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 25L, 29L, NA, 27L, 25L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 
2L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 27L, NA, 2L, 
29L, 27L, 25L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 2L, 
29L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 25L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 
24L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 25L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 
25L, 28L, 22L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 
14L, 28L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 28L, 24L, 2L, 25L, 3L, 14L, NA, 3L, 
27L, 26L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 25L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 16L, 27L, 
3L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 
14L, 27L, 2L, 28L, 24L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 
29L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 28L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 29L, 2L, 25L, 
29L, 3L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 
24L, 16L, 14L, 22L, 16L, 24L, 2L, 28L, 28L, 3L, 22L, 16L, 16L, 
2L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 
16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 27L, 4L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 27L, 2L, 25L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 27L, 
3L, 27L, 23L, NA, 2L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 14L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 16L, NA, 3L, 25L, 27L, 23L, 29L, 2L, 14L, 14L, NA, 4L, 9L, 
22L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 4L, 29L, NA, 24L, 
27L, 16L, 16L, 3L, NA, 16L, 2L, 4L, 16L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 25L, 26L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 2L, NA, 
29L, 4L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 23L, 16L, 4L, 25L, 27L, 
3L, 25L, 2L, 25L, 4L, 14L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 25L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 23L, NA, 2L, 
3L, 27L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 
29L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 27L, NA, 16L, 25L, NA, 2L, 28L, 3L, 
3L, 28L, 28L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 
28L, 3L, 28L, 16L, 14L, 27L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 27L, 2L, NA, 27L, 
29L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 25L, NA, 29L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 
16L, 28L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, 27L, 2L, 14L, 27L, NA, NA, 3L, 24L, 
28L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 26L, 4L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 29L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 23L, 29L, 3L, 
29L, 2L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 16L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 2L, 
25L, 28L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 29L, 14L, NA, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
29L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 29L, 25L, 3L, 14L, 16L, NA, 2L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 27L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 
14L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 14L, 
27L, 2L, 29L, 2L, NA, 3L, 27L, 4L, 24L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 29L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 16L, 3L, NA, 24L, 4L, 16L, 3L, 
29L, 24L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 29L, NA, 3L, 29L, 23L, 
14L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 
16L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 25L, 24L, 14L, 16L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 22L, 24L, 
3L, 14L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 4L, 14L, 29L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 
3L, 28L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 28L, 14L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 27L, NA, 
22L, 4L, 28L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 24L, 4L, 24L, 4L, 25L, 10L, 
3L, 10L, 24L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 29L, NA, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 
3L, 25L, 29L, 10L, 28L, 25L, 7L, 14L, NA, 3L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 
29L, 10L, 25L, NA, 25L, 25L, 3L, 25L, 24L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 
3L, 9L, 2L, 27L, 23L, 3L, 24L, 2L, 28L, 23L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 
25L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 27L, 27L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 
9L, 16L, 26L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, NA, 24L, 27L, 10L, 
10L, 27L, 10L, 27L, 10L, 14L, 9L, 26L, 9L, 2L, 29L, 24L, 10L, 
3L, 28L, 9L, 29L, 16L, 10L, 25L, 10L, 29L, 27L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 
10L, 9L, 4L, 29L, 16L, 9L, 16L, NA, 3L, 28L, 3L, NA, 29L, 29L, 
9L, 9L, 2L, 16L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 27L, NA, NA, 28L, 29L, 10L, 
27L, 16L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 27L, 27L, 9L, 16L, NA, 27L, 9L, 
28L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 9L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 16L, NA, 10L, 
9L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 29L, 29L, 10L, 10L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 
27L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 26L, 4L, 3L, 16L, 29L, 27L, 
2L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 2L, 26L, 27L, 25L), levels = c("N.P.", 
"PP", "PSOE", "Ciudadanos", "En Com├║ Podem", "M├®s Comprom├¡s", 
"ERC", "JxCat", "EAJ-PNV", "EH Bildu", "CCa-NC", "Na+", "PACMA", 
"VOX", "CUP", "Unidas Podemos", "BNG", "PRC", "M├ís Pa├¡s", 
"En Com├║n-Unidas Podemos", "Teruel Existe", "Nulo", "No ten├¡a derecho a voto", 
"No ten├¡a edad", "Otros partidos", "En blanco", "No vot├│", 
"No recuerda", "N.C."), class = "factor", label = "Recuerdo de voto en las elecciones generales de noviembre de 2019 [recodificada]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2787L))
```

I am doing an analysis of the voting preference in my country, Spain, and I am interested in subsetting the data, so that I can take only 5 main parties into consideration for posterior data treatment.

I am trying to run the following code in `base R`, which should do the job; however, for some reason, it doesn't:

```
CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO <- sub("\\(NO LEER\\) ", "", CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO)
RecuerdoDeVoto <- subset(CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO, RECUERDO == "21" & RECUERDO == "2" & RECUERDO == "4" & RECUERDO == "1" & RECUERDO == "18")
CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO <- factor(CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO, labels = RecuerdoDeVoto)
```

Clarification: as can be seen, I am trying to select the 5 main Spanish political parties ("21" for Unidas Podemos, "2" for PSOE, "4" for Ciudadanos, "1" for PP, and "18 for VOX), where "RECUERDO" stands for the variable 'voting preference in the last Spanish General Elections.

I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong here, since when I try to run `length(RecuerdoDeVoto)` I obtain a 0.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

P.S. I know how to do this in `dplyr`, but I really need to find out how to do this in `base R` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO` in provided sample is already a factor and you should subset it by using factor levels: `subset(CIS_data_5, CIS.RECUERDO == "PP")`

Another issue is in your logical expression, you probably meant to use OR (`|`), but currently it reads: "*where RECUERDO is 21 **AND** RECUERDO is 2 **AND** ...*"

To get entries for top 5 parties from provided dataframe, this should be enough:

```r
# get top 5 from sorted frequency table, it's names are factor levels 
top_5 <- sort(table(CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO), decreasing = T)[1:5]
# just subset with []
CIS_data_5[CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO %in% names(top_5),]
# or with subset (returns data.frame):
subset(CIS_data_5, CIS.RECUERDO %in% names(top_5))
# or if you prefer to define the search criteria manually (still a data.frame):
subset(CIS_data_5, CIS.RECUERDO %in% c("PSOE", "PP", "N.C.", "No vot├│", "Unidas Podemos"))
# or with subset that returns a vector: 
subset(CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO, CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO %in% c("PSOE", "PP", "N.C.", "No vot├│", "Unidas Podemos"))
```

Comment: Dear @margusl, thank you very much for your answer! The only issue is that 'abstention' is in the ```top_5```, and I am interested in not including it. Therefore, I need to find some other way of listing the 5 main parties, without the abstention factor. If you have any hint on how to do this, I'll certainly much appreciate it! Many thanks!

Comment: Besides, I've assigned a variable to ```subset(CIS_data_5, CIS.RECUERDO %in% names(top_5))``` and measured its ```length```, and it says ```2```, which is impossible given the total amount of those who voted for the 5 main parties in Spain.

Comment: `subset(CIS_data_5, ... )` returns data.frame and length of a data.frame is a number of variables (columns). If you want a vector you can pass a single column to `subset()`. I added few more examples to my answer.

Comment: Also, as your provided sample data consists of a data.frame with a singe column that's already a factor but in your code sample you are filtering by numeric strings(!) and creating a factor again, make sure you are actually working with the same dataset you have included in your question.  When you executed my code, length for that `subset()` result should have been 1 (i.e there's a single column in data.frame), another indication that you either wanted to include some other variant of your data or you have applied something extra on your current working copy.

Comment: Cool! Many thanks for your useful remarks! Everything is in order now. Many thanks once again, @margusl!