# Error when plotting a boxplot in R: `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, ggpubr

I have an issue with the following code when trying to plot a boxplot:

```
library(ggpubr)

CIS_data_5 <- data.frame(
  CIS$RECUERDO,
  CIS$P20
)

CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO <- sub("\\(NO LEER\\) ", "", CIS_data_5$CIS.RECUERDO)
RECUERDO <- subset(CIS_data_5, CIS.RECUERDO %in% c("Unidas Podemos", "PSOE", "Ciudadanos", "PP", "VOX"))
RecuerdoDeVoto <- RECUERDO$CIS.RECUERDO

P20 <- as.integer(as.character(CIS_data_5$CIS.P20))

P20labs <- c("16-29", "30-44", "45-64", ">65", "N.C.")
cut_points <- c(16, 30, 45, 65, Inf)

i <- findInterval(P20, cut_points)
P20_fac <- P20labs[i]
P20_fac[is.na(P20)] <- P20labs[length(P20labs)]
P20_fac <- factor(P20_fac, levels = P20labs)

CIS_data_5$CIS.P20 <- P20
CIS_data_5$P20_range <- P20_fac

P20_range <-as.vector(CIS_data_5$P20_range)


#Boxplot of Voting Preference by Age

ggboxplot(CIS_data_5, x = "RecuerdoDeVoto", y = "P20_range", 
          color = "RecuerdoDeVoto", palette = c("LightGreen", "Green", "Forest Green", "Brown", "Purple"),
          order = c("16-29", "30-44", "45-64", ">65", "N.C."),
          ylab = "Voting Preference in 2019 Spanish General Elections", xlab = "Age Intervals of the Respondents")
```

I've checked that my syntax is correct by looking at the instructions for `?ggboxplot`, yet I still get the error `` Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected ``.

I really don't understand what is going on here, since everything seems to be perfectly defined.

Partial `dput(CIS_data_5)` is, as follows:

```
structure(list(CIS.RECUERDO = structure(c(3L, 3L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 27L, NA, 29L, 29L, 27L, 3L, NA, 14L, 3L, 28L, 
3L, 16L, 2L, 28L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 16L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 25L, 2L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 4L, NA, 
2L, NA, 28L, 2L, 28L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 29L, NA, 16L, 25L, 24L, 28L, 
24L, 29L, 2L, 24L, 4L, 2L, 22L, 27L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 3L, 
16L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 
2L, 29L, 28L, 2L, 29L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 28L, NA, 
29L, 27L, 22L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 
NA, 29L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 
27L, 29L, 2L, 29L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 24L, 14L, 3L, 
28L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 
2L, 29L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 22L, 29L, 14L, NA, 28L, 2L, 24L, 3L, 
29L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 28L, 25L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 
14L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 25L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 
14L, 16L, 24L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 27L, 3L, NA, 
27L, 26L, 26L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 16L, 24L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 25L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 29L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 29L, 2L, 
16L, 3L, 29L, 26L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 24L, 23L, 
2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 29L, NA, 22L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 25L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 25L, 
28L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 24L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 
3L, 16L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 24L, 2L, 4L, 27L, 24L, 
16L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 14L, 16L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 
16L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 27L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 29L, 
27L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 23L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 
27L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 4L, 2L, 27L, 29L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
24L, 27L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 2L, 29L, 28L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 
14L, 2L, 27L, 14L, NA, 4L, 29L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 27L, 4L, 26L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 28L, 
2L, 3L, 25L, 28L, 24L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
26L, 14L, 29L, 23L, 3L, 24L, 29L, 28L, NA, 29L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 23L, 27L, 3L, NA, 29L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 3L, 
28L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 16L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 16L, 
3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 
29L, 4L, 28L, 14L, 25L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 26L, 24L, 3L, 
27L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
16L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 22L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 27L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
27L, 29L, 2L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 29L, 16L, 26L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 
14L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 16L, NA, 23L, 
27L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 
29L, 4L, 28L, 2L, 2L, NA, 27L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 27L, 
4L, 29L, 26L, 29L, 16L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 16L, 27L, 
2L, 9L, NA, 3L, 3L, 14L, 29L, 28L, 2L, 24L, 3L, 29L, 25L, 3L, 
3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 2L, NA, NA, 27L, 4L, 4L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 25L, 16L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 
29L, 27L, 2L, 16L, 16L, NA, 3L, 16L, 28L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 25L, 
29L, 27L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 29L, 28L, 
25L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 3L, NA, 25L, 16L, 27L, 25L, 28L, 
29L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 2L, 
3L, 29L, 25L, NA, 14L, 3L, 27L, 4L, 26L, 2L, NA, 4L, 27L, 2L, 
26L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 24L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 24L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 26L, 4L, 3L, 27L, 
14L, 3L, 29L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 28L, 16L, 3L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
29L, 27L, 22L, 28L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA, 29L, 16L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 28L, 14L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 22L, 14L, 3L, 
14L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 3L, 25L, 29L, 14L, 16L, 2L, 
3L, 16L, NA, 3L, 28L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 2L, 
28L, 2L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 25L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 26L, 
29L, 28L, 29L, 2L, 16L, 22L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 25L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 29L, 24L, 29L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 27L, 29L, NA, 14L, 3L, 
3L, NA, 29L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 22L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 
3L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 4L, 29L, 4L, 16L, 3L, 23L, 
28L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
3L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 28L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 14L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 28L, 29L, 
16L, 4L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 
29L, 14L, 29L, 26L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 
16L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 27L, 16L, 27L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 4L, 
16L, NA, 3L, NA, 27L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 
5L, 7L, 2L, 23L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 5L, 29L, 28L, NA, 27L, 7L, 7L, 
3L, 7L, 29L, 8L, 3L, 27L, 28L, NA, 3L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 5L, 
3L, 28L, 7L, 4L, 25L, 28L, 3L, 3L, NA, 24L, 29L, 4L, 28L, 2L, 
3L, 28L, 27L, 25L, NA, 28L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 28L, NA, 
3L, 3L, NA, 27L, 5L, 7L, NA, 29L, 27L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 25L, 24L, 
8L, 3L, 26L, 28L, 3L, 5L, 29L, NA, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 7L, 
27L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 3L, NA, 29L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 28L, 
3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 29L, NA, 3L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 3L, NA, 
4L, 3L, 27L, 28L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, NA, 7L, 27L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
29L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 8L, 27L, 29L, 28L, 7L, NA, NA, 29L, 
7L, 27L, 3L, 5L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 22L, 29L, 8L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 
3L, 28L, 27L, 3L, 5L, 27L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 27L, 8L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 
28L, 4L, NA, 28L, 29L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 27L, 3L, 8L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 27L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 
28L, 7L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 24L, 24L, 5L, 27L, 29L, 4L, 29L, 
23L, 27L, 2L, 7L, 27L, 28L, 7L, 28L, 3L, 7L, 22L, 5L, 7L, 29L, 
29L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 22L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 24L, 28L, 5L, NA, 
28L, 23L, 5L, 7L, 27L, 27L, 7L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 27L, 7L, 
5L, 14L, NA, 25L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 29L, 4L, 4L, 7L, NA, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 26L, 24L, 3L, 5L, 29L, 29L, 4L, 29L, 
29L, 3L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 7L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 27L, 7L, 3L, 
29L, 3L, 26L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 29L, NA, NA, 28L, 29L, 7L, 5L, 
29L, 27L, 7L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 29L, 7L, 3L, 24L, 27L, 3L, 
8L, 3L, 5L, NA, 3L, 28L, 8L, 27L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 7L, 28L, 24L, 
27L, 23L, 7L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 29L, 25L, 28L, 7L, 
28L, NA, 28L, 7L, 7L, 27L, 3L, 29L, 8L, NA, 27L, 27L, 8L, 7L, 
25L, 3L, 7L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 3L, 24L, 7L, 
7L, 28L, 26L, 22L, 7L, NA, 3L, 29L, 5L, 28L, 24L, 2L, 24L, 7L, 
14L, 8L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 25L, 7L, 3L, 26L, 27L, 5L, 27L, 27L, 
24L, 2L, 29L, 5L, 3L, 28L, 8L, 29L, 5L, 28L, NA, 7L, 8L, 16L, 
27L, 29L, 16L, 27L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 29L, 4L, 3L, 16L, 25L, 29L, 16L, 
3L, 16L, 27L, 16L, 29L, 14L, 3L, NA, 29L, 3L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 
3L, 3L, 29L, 4L, NA, 3L, 29L, 16L, 28L, 25L, 4L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 
16L, 29L, 16L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 25L, 3L, 14L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 16L,  
3L, 27L, 2L, 25L, 4L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 27L, 
3L, 27L, 23L, NA, 2L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 29L, 14L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 16L, NA, 3L, 25L, 27L, 23L, 29L, 2L, 14L, 14L, NA, 4L, 9L, 
22L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 4L, 29L, NA, 24L, 
27L, 16L, 16L, 3L, NA, 16L, 2L, 4L, 16L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 25L, 26L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 16L, 2L, NA, 
29L, 4L, 2L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 23L, 16L, 4L, 25L, 27L, 
3L, 25L, 2L, 25L, 4L, 14L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 25L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 3L, 23L, NA, 2L, 
3L, 27L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 
29L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 27L, NA, 16L, 25L, NA, 2L, 28L, 3L, 
3L, 28L, 28L, 3L, 24L, 3L, 29L, 14L, 3L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 29L, 
28L, 3L, 28L, 16L, 14L, 27L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 27L, 2L, NA, 27L, 
29L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 25L, NA, 29L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 
16L, 28L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, 27L, 2L, 14L, 27L, NA, NA, 3L, 24L, 
28L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 26L, 4L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 29L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 23L, 29L, 3L, 
29L, 2L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 16L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 2L, 
25L, 28L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 29L, 14L, NA, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
29L, 3L, 27L, 14L, 29L, 25L, 3L, 14L, 16L, NA, 2L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 27L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 
14L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 29L, 29L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 14L, 
27L, 2L, 29L, 2L, NA, 3L, 27L, 4L, 24L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 29L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 16L, 3L, NA, 24L, 4L, 16L, 3L, 
29L, 24L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 29L, NA, 3L, 29L, 23L, 
14L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 
16L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 25L, 24L, 14L, 16L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 22L, 24L, 
3L, 14L, 27L, 3L, 27L, 4L, 14L, 29L, 2L, 14L, 27L, 3L, 3L, 27L, 
3L, 28L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 28L, 14L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 27L, NA, 
22L, 4L, 28L, 16L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 24L, 4L, 24L, 4L, 25L, 10L, 
3L, 10L, 24L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 29L, NA, 27L, NA, 3L, 29L, 
3L, 25L, 29L, 10L, 28L, 25L, 7L, 14L, NA, 3L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 
29L, 10L, 25L, NA, 25L, 25L, 3L, 25L, 24L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 
3L, 9L, 2L, 27L, 23L, 3L, 24L, 2L, 28L, 23L, 3L, 27L, 16L, 3L, 
25L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 27L, 27L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 27L, 3L, 
9L, 16L, 26L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, NA, 24L, 27L, 10L, 
10L, 27L, 10L, 27L, 10L, 14L, 9L, 26L, 9L, 2L, 29L, 24L, 10L, 
3L, 28L, 9L, 29L, 16L, 10L, 25L, 10L, 29L, 27L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 
10L, 9L, 4L, 29L, 16L, 9L, 16L, NA, 3L, 28L, 3L, NA, 29L, 29L, 
9L, 9L, 2L, 16L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 27L, NA, NA, 28L, 29L, 10L, 
27L, 16L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 27L, 27L, 9L, 16L, NA, 27L, 9L, 
28L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 9L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 16L, NA, 10L, 
9L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 29L, 29L, 10L, 10L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 
27L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 26L, 4L, 3L, 16L, 29L, 27L, 
2L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 2L, 26L, 27L, 25L), levels = c("N.P.", 
"PP", "PSOE", "Ciudadanos", "En Com├║ Podem", "M├®s Comprom├¡s", 
"ERC", "JxCat", "EAJ-PNV", "EH Bildu", "CCa-NC", "Na+", "PACMA", 
"VOX", "CUP", "Unidas Podemos", "BNG", "PRC", "M├ís Pa├¡s", 
"En Com├║n-Unidas Podemos", "Teruel Existe", "Nulo", "No ten├¡a derecho a voto", 
"No ten├¡a edad", "Otros partidos", "En blanco", "No vot├│", 
"No recuerda", "N.C."), class = "factor", label = "Recuerdo de voto en las elecciones generales de noviembre de 2019 [recodificada]"), 
    CIS.P20 = c("63", "48", "43", "51", "47", "39", "42", "65", 
    "70", "49", "63", "37", "52", "39", "50", "50", "34", "72", 
    "47", "60", "28", "38", "39", "20", "23", "49", "17", "67", 
    "81", "58", "69", "39", "42", "55", "55", "79", "44", "27", 
    "67", "22", "41", "55", "74", "34", "39", "59", "34", "77", 
    "41", "31", "55", "46", "29", "30", "44", "39", "56", "48", 
    "56", "18", "54", "19", "59", "54", "16", "43", "55", "23", 
    "64", "74", "65", "23", "23", "24", "56", "50", "50", "80", 
    "55", "53", "44", "39", "69", "55", "36", "44", "18", "42", 
    "60", "65", "42", "65", "75", "65", "56", "71", "72", "48", 
    "60", "46", "73", "18", "31", "58", "40", "55", "47", "32", 
    "73", "61", "30", "55", "37", "43", "26", "53", "65", "37", 
    "40", "62", "32", "47", "51", "64", "55", "38", "32", "49", 
    "23", "52", "82", "52", "67", "75", "20", "70", "60", "55", 
    "51", "61", "65", "28", "88", "46", "48", "62", "73", "52", 
    "70", "31", "53", "47", "30", "60", "48", "24", "62", "25", 
    "24", "48", "56", "46", "46", "36", "43", "41", "83", "30", 
    "78", "53", "74", "45", "62", "36", "51", "65", "55", "45", 
    "29", "69", "31", "75", "23", "59", "64", "83", "48", "39", 
    "73", "42", "49", "48", "62", "65", "67", "30", "36", "31", 
    "62", "74", "52", "49", "26", "52", "65", "24", "56", "66", 
    "46", "50", "41", "20", "39", "66", "21", "42", "67", "83", 
    "23", "54", "48", "66", "56", "68", "54", "75", "58", "25", 
    "66", "41", "56", "66", "69", "50", "48", "50", "54", "43", 
    "63", "20", "46", "65", "23", "60", "65", "56", "68", "69", 
    "47", "58", "80", "37", "47", "39", "50", "55", "49", "56", 
    "34", "63", "61", "50", "39", "27", "50", "34", "23", "45", 
    "73", "70", "31", "52", "32", "16", "50", "55", "65", "65", 
    "68", "65", "57", "52", "44", "69", "19", "44", "62", "66", 
    "73", "25", "44", "51", "31", "24", "69", "51", "34", "64", 
    "74", "54", "21", "50", "40", "67", "18", "62", "67", "66", 
    "41", "80", "38", "50", "60", "70", "60", "24", "34", "47", 
    "64", "62", "60", "22", "46", "39", "22", "36", "60", "67", 
    "72", "52", "71", "54", "41", "61", "50", "50", "19", "35", 
    "36", "60", "38", "35", "56", "38", "48", "48", "47", "75", 
    "58", "42", "71", "53", "59", "50", "29", "73", "65", "44", 
    "40", "30", "25", "72", "76", "61", "58", "38", "44", "72", 
    "39", "47", "51", "48", "49", "46", "75", "19", "57", "58", 
    "56", "66", "44", "25", "44", "63", "44", "52", "77", "32", 
    "52", "60", "32", "62", "68", "25", "50", "23", "40", "47", 
    "66", "61", "54", "61", "63", "19", "50", "49", "52", "18", 
    "46", "65", "65", "44", "26", "84", "44", "55", "65", "30", 
    "70", "46", "73", "28", "51", "33", "36", "61", "42", "73", 
    "90", "43", "37", "76", "17", "61", "42", "38", "63", "69", 
    "49", "59", "65", "55", "33", "42", "43", "55", "50", "65", 
    "54", "49", "66", "43", "54", "45", "80", "20", "27", "42", 
    "63", "53", "69", "56", "52", "46", "56", "50", "16", "74", 
    "80", "64", "75", "16", "61", "22", "70", "57", "33", "26", 
    "47", "46", "65", "67", "65", "58", "60", "51", "50", "25", 
    "39", "68", "34", "58", "55", "53", "43", "42", "61", "70", 
    "44", "52", "68", "68", "70", "54", "53", "61", "40", "26", 
    "32", "57", "46", "48", "32", "23", "30", "54", "54", "62", 
    "40", "61", "52", "52", "55", "77", "57", "40", "36", "45", 
    "33", "69", "23", "35", "47", "53", "56", "31", "34", "90", 
    "34", "53", "78", "38", "64", "37", "47", "50", "77", "53", 
    "51", "46", "46", "38", "39", "67", "40", "42", "51", "54", 
    "26", "31", "60", "76", "23", "53", "65", "33", "67", "19", 
    "68", "39", "28", "49", "54", "62", "74", "37", "54", "24", 
    "44", "35", "88", "70", "86", "49", "70", "67", "50", "65", 
    "73", "52", "18", "35", "18", "72", "66", "44", "25", "45", 
    "61", "22", "62", "79", "73", "75", "62", "54", "58", "61", 
    "77", "74", "53", "49", "47", "43", "74", "54", "40", "30", 
    "71", "52", "27", "63", "66", "58", "74", "34", "25", "65", 
    "57", "34", "54", "73", "39", "64", "42", "24", "30", "31", 
    "54", "26", "64", "44", "45", "45", "62", "72", "74", "64", 
    "35", "66", "58", "61", "34", "66", "62", "62", "40", "20", 
    "67", "55", "36", "51", "21", "79", "50", "44", "55", "78", 
    "41", "54", "54", "54", "66", "58", "42", "56", "34", "64", 
    "67", "76", "65", "52", "57", "65", "62", "56", "47", "41", 
    "38", "52", "67", "42", "75", "44", "37", "52", "53", "30", 
    "52", "39", "36", "65", "75", "51", "54", "63", "74", "61", 
    "88", "50", "46", "49", "40", "90", "56", "35", "51", "70", 
    "25", "54", "59", "77", "55", "29", "44", "64", "60", "74", 
    "69", "67", "56", "55", "50", "51", "47", "17", "66", "39", 
    "64", "37", "64", "72", "43", "27", "50", "20", "46", "22", 
    "21", "66", "48", "39", "21", "66", "40", "25", "67", "69", 
    "90", "27", "70", "57", "32", "30", "54", "67", "44", "21", 
    "26", "74", "55", "51", "32", "29", "42", "29", "71", "48", 
    "74", "70", "46", "46", "42", "44", "54", "22", "35", "65", 
    "23", "17", "46", "74", "54", "86", "39", "47", "23", "75", 
    "39", "36", "52", "32", "39", "57", "48", "40", "47", "27", 
    "53", "61", "46", "55", "52", "27", "34", "36", "59", "35", 
    "45", "53", "60", "17", "45", "75", "30", "38", "49", "21", 
    "50", "38", "40", "46", "33", "57", "74", "55", "57", "31", 
    "61", "86", "36", "51", "33", "52", "53", "46", "80", "49", 
    "70", "74", "49", "81", "44", "46", "22", "23", "73", "29", 
    "38", "80", "44", "31", "67", "50", "22", "35", "29", "30", 
    "61", "24", "76", "60", "41", "42", "74", "41", "53", "44", 
    "29", "47", "62", "51", "55", "72", "54", "46", "40", "49", 
    "61", "54", "74", "26", "41", "36", "24", "28", "62", "52", 
    "58", "60", "34", "67", "57", "68", "41", "64", "52", "48", 
    "65", "43", "40", "50", "21", "70", "40", "26", "31", "68", 
    "47", "35", "35", "56", "70", "37", "27", "65", "28", "86", 
    "37", "20", "71", "48", "59", "72", "67", "68", "59", "33", 
    "47", "75", "74", "39", "63", "44", "60", "31", "68", "70", 
    "28", "56", "21", "87", "45", "37", "46", "47", "23", "56", 
    "49", "19", "16", "49", "24", "35", "48", "82", "24", "63", 
    "87", "46", "55", "53", "71", "65", "60", "78", "33", "46", 
    "26", "50", "66", "70", "72", "36", "63", "65", "43", "70", 
    "54", "48", "17", "50", "21", "45", "40", "33", "32", "45", 
    "55", "53", "46", "61", "84", "51", "29", "50", "57", "47", 
    "81", "70", "40", "28", "91", "69", "72", "39", "32", "39", 
    "50", "47", "42", "71", "20", "69", "45", "68", "77", "56", 
    "53", "45", "17", "84", "50", "61", "59", "51", "48", "45", 
    "72", "76", "57", "78", "45", "59", "49", "32", "68", "68", 
    "30", "61", "73", "58", "36", "51", "42", "36", "47", "43", 
    "25", "30", "23", "68", "78", "58", "25", "79", "56", "73", 
    "22", "51", "41", "34", "41", "67", "29", "51", "19", "64", 
    "35", "57", "50", "24", "38", "72", "20", "58", "55", "46", 
    "41", "64", "46", "56", "18", "28", "60", "44", "57", "56", 
    "72", "82", "52", "65", "40", "62", "40", "67", "75", "53", 
    "64", "55", "58", "60", "60", "57", "65", "78", "25", "57", 
    "46", "41", "41", "75", "69", "24", "18", "72", "78", "59", 
    "60", "46", "76", "63", "18", "70", "56", "55", "47", "37", 
    "38", "52", "54", "45", "21", "40", "17", "56", "18", "30", 
    "50", "65", "63", "32", "45", "70", "55", "39", "54", "62", 
    "64", "63", "31", "29", "20", "46", "44", "47", "75", "49", 
    "70", "73", "66", "45", "63", "62", "67", "45", "50", "80", 
    "22", "69", "24", "38", "74", "40", "34", "62", "53", "71", 
    "88", "85", "62", "79", "58", "45", "55", "60", "18", "55", 
    "50", "65", "25", "50", "64", "48", "43", "23", "21", "75", 
    "52", "61", "80", "63", "62", "42", "38", "28", "54", "55", 
    "59", "70", "50", "36", "36", "66", "48", "64", "26", "40", 
    "40", "59", "21", "40", "45", "37", "60", "46", "38", "71", 
    "52", "62", "35", "40", "63", "38", "73", "62", "61", "60", 
    "46", "43", "28", "83", "33", "57", "37", "48", "48", "26", 
    "62", "65", "36", "17", "37", "63", "53", "54", "47", "44", 
    "67", "25", "50", "60", "58", "17", "56", "38", "18", "56", 
    "44", "54", "59", "26", "59", "83", "51", "42", "42", "69", 
    "59", "54", "73", "39", "34", "72", "37", "31", "79", "40", 
    "18", "75", "66", "61", "65", "47", "21", "67", "58", "74", 
    "51", "51", "22", "29", "64", "37", "84", "55", "66", "71", 
    "59", "25", "45", "61", "68", "45", "32", "47", "52", "51", 
    "24", "56", "17", "49", "72", "42", "40", "40", "70", "63", 
    "55", "51", "40", "51", "22", "56", "59", "37", "70", "53", 
    "46", "64", "77", "30", "63", "28", "38", "35", "63", "36", 
    "65", "48", "38", "82", "45", "54", "49", "56", "47", "58", 
    "58", "41", "39", "42", "25", "35", "93", "37", "71", "69", 
    "82", "67", "29", "53", "39", "65", "48", "54", "55", "82", 
    "48", "59", "66", "87", "54", "62", "24", "58", "69", "20", 
    "50", "67", "31", "52", "60", "37", "42", "50", "76", "66", 
    "17", "74", "64", "60", "37", "59", "46", "64", "50", "37", 
    "50", "50", "59", "63", "53", "54", "56", "74", "42", "62", 
    "40", "43", "23", "55", "52", "65", "90", "31", "54", "57", 
    "67", "46", "51", "58", "34", "81", "36", "37", "79", "53", 
    "41", "58", "79", "71", "16", "18", "42", "43", "25", "48", 
    "50", "53", "45", "53", "54", "72", "39", "70", "38", "57", 
    "50", "20", "68", "86", "55", "27", "52", "52", "23", "22", 
    "39", "52", "46", "74", "59", "65", "65", "78", "57", "39", 
    "76", "17", "71", "51", "63", "56", "42", "25", "31", "86", 
    "48", "39", "55", "31", "60", "79", "60", "74", "27", "41", 
    "57", "69", "67", "52", "68", "58", "62", "23", "66", "58", 
    "74", "29", "59", "63", "18", "66", "42", "18", "63", "72", 
    "46", "38", "32", "67", "26", "77", "54", "55", "72", "58", 
    "68", "53", "46", "29", "68", "58", "54", "35", "71", "46", 
    "26", "52", "46", "64", "51", "50", "65", "34", "62", "43", 
    "68", "45", "32", "42", "50", "63", "49", "47", "51", "38", 
    "32", "29", "39", "71", "43", "73", "55", "63", "47", "43", 
    "47", "36", "39", "58", "59", "82", "33", "78", "45", "46", 
    "44", "72", "59", "50", "55", "45", "47", "31", "60", "42", 
    "51", "43", "38", "53", "50", "45", "58", "74", "72", "65", 
    "38", "31", "79", "59", "65", "58", "55", "36", "56", "74", 
    "37", "47", "30", "37", "64", "75", "44", "59", "73", "55", 
    "39", "38", "49", "40", "56", "29", "31", "47", "52", "66", 
    "60", "69", "55", "58", "39", "71", "82", "62", "63", "56", 
    "62", "41", "40", "40", "72", "81", "62", "19", "47", "63", 
    "41", "17", "39", "55", "58", "45", "49", "45", "44", "68", 
    "37", "34", "46", "73", "18", "33", "45", "46", "50", "79", 
    "74", "32", "19", "57", "47", "90", "46", "28", "74", "27", 
    "46", "64", "49", "28", "45", "16", "31", "49", "50", "32", 
    "34", "65", "67", "40", "48", "65", "25", "38", "37", "62", 
    "58", "69", "20", "56", "43", "28", "61", "59", "24", "39", 
    "37", "48", "73", "32", "74", "44", "59", "49", "25", "45", 
    "39", "30", "55", "57", "20", "54", "49", "43", "21", "55", 
    "59", "40", "65", "72", "55", "68", "52", "56", "63", "63", 
    "38", "70", "35", "23", "56", "61", "42", "54", "66", "35", 
    "51", "60", "48", "86", "18", "30", "64", "36", "49", "20", 
    "57", "17", "55", "50", "28", "28", "17", "57", "32", "22", 
    "68", "45", "42", "26", "52", "64", "38", "60", "47", "45", 
    "31", "36", "47", "35", "55", "44", "18", "61", "49", "71", 
    "61", "36", "61", "40", "29", "30", "30", "68", "46", "42", 
    "49", "82", "44", "77", "52", "66", "51", "47", "25", "65", 
    "59", "58", "55", "49", "41", "77", "39", "78", "65", "28", 
    "57", "58", "64", "44", "45", "24", "55", "26", "76", "82", 
    "52", "35", "64", "81", "64", "49", "40", "45", "73", "60", 
    "30", "33", "47", "44", "32", "33", "58", "87", "69", "55", 
    "44", "33", "54", "50", "31", "52", "33", "16", "58", "37", 
    "53", "72", "38", "40", "41", "61", "40", "30", "51", "41", 
    "47", "30", "72", "48", "40", "78", "50", "59", "40", "28", 
    "41", "71", "45", "54", "50", "54", "35", "62", "59", "37", 
    "60", "38", "22", "45", "62", "22", "69", "62", "20", "67", 
    "36", "87", "38", "56", "58", "45", "43", "47", "58", "50", 
    "81", "85", "52", "59", "48", "26", "66", "41", "63", "56", 
    "25", "65", "46", "54", "56", "58", "35", "42", "44", "32", 
    "62", "40", "63", "30", "64", "65", "49", "31", "41", "47", 
    "42", "86", "56", "45", "49", "51", "62", "47", "32", "34", 
    "48", "41", "32", "40", "37", "50", "57", "40", "52", "21", 
    "61", "18", "68", "54", "44", "25", "56", "60", "25", "46", 
    "58", "50", "58", "45", "21", "27", "43", "33", "55", "50", 
    "52", "38", "44", "23", "47", "70", "68", "27", "31", "50", 
    "38", "42", "66", "47", "51", "24", "58", "41", "43", "51", 
    "61", "71", "36", "36", "34", "31", "36", "31", "23", "27", 
    "59", "19", "36", "41", "81", "79", "24", "53", "49", "65", 
    "35", "51", "52", "46", "70", "52", "75", "35", "76", "43", 
    "80", "59", "48", "65", "68", "49", "58", "42", "32", "45", 
    "70", "35", "58", "61", "65", "59", "42", "59", "58", "38", 
    "41", "67", "38", "67", "42", "55", "32", "65", "23", "36", 
    "51", "83", "34", "41", "60", "62", "45", "42", "57", "37", 
    "53", "51", "31", "30", "42", "62", "41", "66", "32", "69", 
    "75", "53", "38", "34", "45", "59", "57", "22", "48", "71", 
    "29", "60", "69", "62", "79", "79", "33", "70", "82", "51", 
    "66", "45", "27", "74", "48", "27", "48", "32", "28", "59", 
    "39", "61", "56", "40", "56", "48", "42", "16", "29", "44", 
    "44", "44", "23", "63", "37", "54", "74", "51", "49", "52", 
    "28", "53", "47", "37", "18", "45", "36", "66", "53", "19", 
    "23", "65", "53", "45", "46", "37", "52", "77", "61", "60", 
    "41", "28", "66", "69", "53", "28", "37", "40", "43", "37", 
    "48", "39", "37", "67", "41", "26", "61", "33", "42", "47", 
    "71", "17", "51", "28", "86", "71", "58", "52", "20", "78", 
    "49", "66", "49", "53", "44", "50", "59", "83", "33", "45", 
    "56", "65", "73", "63", "58", "31", "48", "58", "61", "76", 
    "44", "61", "88", "23", "36", "34", "27", "50", "40", "36", 
    "49", "59", "67", "18", "51", "20", "66", "24", "65", "75", 
    "39", "18", "46", "28", "51", "57", "82", "59", "33", "23", 
    "35", "75", "53", "84", "80", "38", "59", "67", "60", "44", 
    "66", "37", "38", "42", "73", "76", "47", "48", "73", "46", 
    "45", "65", "79", "39", "19", "60", "58", "61", "68", "50", 
    "66", "66", "60", "52", "45", "17", "73", "56", "50", "45", 
    "50", "55", "48", "75", "75", "70", "52", "42", "25", "36", 
    "42", "32", "48", "61", "43", "51", "68", "49", "41", "51", 
    "74", "24", "45", "70", "60", "72", "32", "34", "17", "46", 
    "56", "41", "44", "31", "62", "67", "59", "44", "76", "40", 
    "70", "23", "20", "71", "60", "66", "40", "26", "41", "50", 
    "48", "56", "86", "50", "78", "53", "47", "68", "46", "67", 
    "59", "49", "65", "55", "36", "51", "91", "55", "38", "57", 
    "40", "29", "73", "53", "52", "84", "61", "61", "64", "57", 
    "43", "70", "28", "60", "27", "57", "47", "26", "47", "51", 
    "76", "34", "43", "46", "50", "37", "30", "65", "79", "47", 
    "74", "48", "39", "34", "64", "51", "41", "72", "72", "49", 
    "44", "22", "45", "57", "62", "68", "70", "70", "50", "41", 
    "35", "70", "76", "58", "46", "45", "67", "42", "78", "40", 
    "62", "78", "38", "17", "62", "27", "52", "49", "61", "45", 
    "77", "67", "42", "18", "74", "65", "20", "49", "38")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2787L))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

**Addendum**

I am very grateful to @RuiBarradas and to @margusl , who helped me with the original code in these 2 previous questions that I made:
[How to convert factor data into intervals in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838767/how-to-convert-factor-data-into-intervals-in-r)
[Issue with subsetting the data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005033/issue-with-subsetting-the-data-in-r)

Comment: You don't have `RecuerdoDeVoto` in your dataframe?

Comment: Hello, @Quinten! If I try to create another ```data.frame```, say, ```CIS_data_6``` before running the ```ggboxplot``` part, I get the following error: ```Error in data.frame(RecuerdoDeVoto, P20_range) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1430, 2787```. Do you know, by chance, how I can override this problem? Many thanks in advance!